# how to access WorkManager attributes value in weblogic server from our application

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic12c, mbeans, workmanagers

I want to access the MaxThreadsConstraint attribute in the WorkManager using MBean Runtime server.
So help me in accessing the  weblogic server's WorkManager attributes value from my Java application

Answer (score 0):

You can access the JMX MBean: MaxThreadsConstraintRuntimeMBean to get information about your workmanager.

JMX in Weblogic 12c: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24415/accesswls.htm#JMXCU145

Runtime MaxThreadsConstraintRuntimeMBean:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/management/runtime/MaxThreadsConstraintRuntimeMBean.html